# Import from angular2's source code using es5

Tags: node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a node application which requires the angular2 HTML parser ([this class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_parser.ts)).

Problem is that `node.js` cannot use `es2015` at the moment, this feature in under development and I can't wait for it to be finished to finish my tool. And I get the error:

```
<my-project>/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_parser.js:13
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How can I `import` the class in my `node.js` app (written in `Typescript`, transpilled to `es5`) ?

*Of course one of the solutions would be to clone angular2's repo and compile the class to es5 by myself, but I want a clean solution, using a regular npm import.*

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "stripInternal": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "test/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which module are you targetting in your tsconfig? It should be `commonjs`

Comment: @Dieterg I added my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Well, if you're transpiling this, it should use `commonjs` modules. So `import * ` wille be replaced by `require(' ')`

Comment: The error is when I try to import angular2's already transpilled code, but since it's es2015 it's using import keyword.